# No GUI on embedded video

Tags: video, youtube, embed

I'm trying to find video hosting provider to embed a video (html5 preferred, with flash fallback would be boss), with enough settings to suit my needs : autoplay / loop / *no gui*.

Just the raw video, playing in loops, for it would be some kind of teaser.

If something like this exists that would be great. So far I'm going with vimeo, which is close enough, but I would love no interface at all, which doesn't seem to be available in vimeo.

Comment: Found a simple tutorial to provide html5 video with flash fallback, I'm trying this out as I type, looks good ! http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/simple-html5-video-flash-fallback-custom-controls/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5 there is a video tag, .  this tag is customizable with looping capabilities as well as all the standard play,pause,volumn,ect.  i use it all the time with my web design and development.  For more info on this tag go here -->

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

one thing to keep in mind with this tag is it is still fairly new as in the last few years.  it supports a number of video formats for which i would recommend set a few different formats because none of the formats are supported across all browsers.  I would suggest making a version for each format MP4,OGG, and WebM.

I hope this helps

Comment: That's quite neat, it does help. I knew about these tags along with <audio> but for some reason I didn't think hosting the video directly would be a good option, or too hard to implement, it doesn't seem so now. thank's